# Require a random file everytime the page is refreshed

Tags: php

I am trying to "require" a random php file each time my web page has been refreshed.

I tried the code bellow but it loads more than one file.. i just used echo to reveal if it is choose one file and note more!

```
$files = array('config/config.php', 'config/config2.php'. 'config/config3.php');

// randomly include a file
echo $files[array_rand($files)];
```

Will this work?

```
$linkName = mt_rand(1,3);
 if ($linkName == 1) require 'config/config.php';
 if ($linkName == 2) require 'config/config2.php';
 if ($linkName == 3) require 'config/config3.php';
```

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Both codes work fine. What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a dot instead of a comma in your array. This is causing a "bug" with your code because when second key is returned you see the output as "two" files because they are concatenated as one entry.